# Handling network exceptions IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, network-programming

I am new to objective-c, I am doing the same app for android and iPhone.

When in Java I use a try-catch block to catch a network exception and handle it.

In Objective-C I am using:

```
[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]
```

So, How can I handle a network exception when parsing that input stream, so if network goes down or there's any problem I can notify user and keep my app working?.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/14/checking-network-reachability-iphone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NSXMLParser then use its delgate method..

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
NSLog(@"Error = %@", parseError);
}
```

Comment: This will get called only after the data download completes. Questions is about handling network errors.

Comment: if network failure at starting then this method should be called

Comment: No, this method is called only if XML parser fails to parse the data. In case the [`initWithContentsOfURL` fails](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-BAJCCBCH), the `NSXMLParser` instance is `nil`. This is not sufficient to know what network error occured.

Comment: this reports a fatal error to the delegate. The parser will stop parsing if network failure or exception occured. Before down voting pleas check

Comment: I dont need to know the error, only if parsing finished ok or not, is this method called if network or server or anything goes wrong?

Comment: @Nanoc in apple documentation they said  this method is called only if XML parser fails to parse the data

Comment: @Kalpesh please edit you answer quoting the Apple documentation. And will you also be able to see the HTTP status code?

Comment: @Nanoc you can check if this method is called then your xml parsing is failed

Comment: @rckoenes op wants only his  parsing successfully or not thats why i am giving this answer .

Comment: Error = Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"

Perfect for me, i even dont need to know what error is.

Answer (score 1):

It is never a good idea to use the `initWithContentsOfURL:` methods.

You are better of retrieving the the data via [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or some library like [`AFNetworking`](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAFNetworking%2FAFNetworking&ei=gW45UonyF6q-0QWi2oHoDw&usg=AFQjCNE6c3SnPVzdrmQ1-UQ5mEf8Kl9JXg&sig2=Yd2kbp6gVPdsHZCJTio2IA&bvm=bv.52288139,d.d2k). This will allow you to handle the HTTP status code and network error.

For example the [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) has a call back method [`– connection:didFailWithError:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection%3adidFailWithError%3a) which will be called in case of an error.
You can then examen the error object to see what went wrong.

Comment: Seems a good way to do it, but i dont need to know html error code, only if parsing was succesful or not.

Comment: I have accepted Kalpesh answer for faster implementation, and better fit of my need, anyway i think your answer was a better way to handle socket errors.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call the URL You can check the internet connectivity.

I suggest you to look the below link
[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

And I suggest for parsing XML file use raptureXML Which is very simple.
https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML

Comment: of course im checking internet connection before doing this, but anyway network can fail while downloading.

Comment: Using NSURLConnection Delegate Methods.